# docusign embedded email notification

Tags: docusignapi

I will create a embedded envelope with 2 recipient in sequential order. How to notify the second user that the first user has signed the document and now he can do the digital signature. Does docusign has any such kind of feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both your recipients are [embedded](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning), then once the first recipient takes an action, DocuSign redirects to the the returnUrl you specify with a [Recipient action](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#determine-action).  Based on the recipient action returned you can take the next steps in your workflow. If you get the **signing_complete** action then you can load the next recipient.

From [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#determine-action)

> There are numerous actions the embedded recipient might take:
>
> - **cancel** - the recipient decides to finish later
> - **decline** - the recipient declines signing
> - **exception** - a processing error occurs during the signing session
> - **fax_pending** - if the recipient choses to print, sign and fax back
> - **id_check_failed** - if authentication was added to the document, this is when the recipient fails
> - **session_timeout** - the signing session times out when recipient goes idle
> - **signing_complete** - the recipient completed signing
> - **ttl_expired** - the token was not used within the timeout period or the token was already accessed
> - **viewing_complete** - a recipient that does not need to sign completes the viewing ceremony

---

If your second recipient is a [remote recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) then DocuSign will automatically notify the second recipient after the first recipient finishes signing.